# Displaying lines with given number of characters

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

I have written such a program which suppose to returns lines which are containing at least 11 characters and 4 digits. I messed up something with types of variables I guess but I cant figure out how should I fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char line[200];
    char *temp[200];
    int i = 0, k=0;

    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),stdin))
    {
        int numberAlpha = 0;
        int numberDigit = 0;
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<strlen(line); i++){
            if(isalpha(line[i])) numberAlpha++;
            else if(isdigit(line[i])) numberDigit++;
        }

        if(numberAlpha+numberDigit>10 && numberDigit>3){
            temp[i]=line;
            i++;
        }
    }
    while(temp[k]!='\0'){
        printf("%s", temp[k]);
        k++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have not copied the successful string, only the pointer. Sadly, the string to which it points, gets overwritten at the next line. Have a look at `strdup`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are assigning the *same* address here:

```
temp[i]=line;
```

and `line` is used in the loop to read as well. That means it's overwritten in every iteration.

Instead, you can use `strdup()` (POSIX function):

```
temp[i] = strdup(line);
```

to copy the lines you are interested in. If `strdup()` not available you can use `malloc()` + `strcpy()` to do the same. Plus, `free()` them later.

In addition, be aware that:

- `fgets()` will read in the newline character if there's room in the buffer which may not be what you want. So, you need to trim it out. You can do it with:

  ```
  line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0; /* trim the trailing newline, if any */
  ```
- The arguments to `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` should be cast to `unsigned char` to avoid potential undefined behaviour i.e. these two lines:

  ```
  if(isalpha(line[i])) numberAlpha++;
  else if(isdigit(line[i])) numberDigit++;
  ```

  should be

  ```
  if(isalpha((unsigned char)line[i])) numberAlpha++;
  else if((unsigned char)isdigit(line[i])) numberDigit++;
  ```

Comment: Ok, I got this, thanks. Is there any other way to write that program which wont require those 'fancy' function?

Comment: Unless there's any need to keep "remember" those lines, you can avoid the copying by printing immediately inside the loop. i.e. you can replacew `temp[i]=line;` with `printf("%s\n", line);`.

Comment: So I made changes according to your suggestions, but now it seems to crash after returning first line which follows the if statement

Comment: It works for me after the changes. See: http://ideone.com/9NSKG2 and the strdup version: http://ideone.com/xmm3k6

Answer (score 1):

You're reusing the same buffer each time, and you're storing a pointer to that buffer in your `temp` array. What you're going to end up with is a bunch of the same pointer in that array, with that pointer pointing at the last line in the file.

What you can do instead is to rewrite your `temp[i]=line` statement to the following:

```
temp[i] = malloc(sizeof(line))
memcpy(temp[i], line, sizeof(line))
```

In so doing, you'll be creating a new array with the contents of the matching line, which won't get overwritten when you come around and read the next line out of the file.

Note that, because you're allocating that on the heap, at the end of your function you'll want to free it:

```
while (temp[k] != '\0') {
    printf(...);
    free(temp[k]);
    k++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As said before , one issue is with copying of
temp[i]=line;
This can be solved by doing a new heap allocation and doing memcopy to temp.
The other issue that i could see is - with the value of variable i. Then temp array will always be assigned to strlen(line) index. You might be thinking of storing in the temp array from 0. Which is not happening.
This can be solved by-

```
int start_index=0;
while(...){  
if(numberAlpha+numberDigit>10 && numberDigit>3){  
        temp[start_index]=line;  
        start_index++;  
    }  
}
```